# The problem of ray selection of mesh corresponding material in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have a model, only one mesh, and material is an array in mesh with 4 ShaderMaterial.[The data structure of the model object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyl0l.png)，[Position of material mark point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cydnm.png)

I want to click the mesh to get the material in the corresponding position, and use Raycaster to get the intersect object. I want to find the corresponding material in the object through the face.materialIndex.How do I get the right material? [intersect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHgIh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a specific `materialIndex`, you can get the corresponding material object like so:

```
const material = mesh.material[ materialIndex ];
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Mesh.material) when using multiple materials per mesh, `Mesh.material` becomes an array of materials.

Comment: I know what you mean. Now, the problem is that I get materialIndex from a ray, and I click anywhere on the model, and the returned materialIndex is 0, and it doesn't return the materialIndex that I want, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Comment: Thank you. When I wanted to create an example, I found that the problem with the GLTFLoader version had been solved.